# How to add a complementary filter for the gyro z axis using a magnetometer?

Tags: math, arduino, gyroscope, magnetometer, mpu

I am using a complementary filter for my gyro X and gyro Y values:

`float angle_x = alpha*gyro_angle_x + (1.0 - alpha)*accel_angle_x;`

However, due to Gyro Z drift, I am using a magnetometer to try and eliminate it.

I have my local inclination angle and the z-axis magnetometer reading but I am not sure how to implement this into the complementary filter.

I've tried guessing (which I know doesn't help) to try this:

```
float angle_z = alpha*gyro_angle_z + ((1.0 -alpha)*accel_angle_y*InclinationAngle)/magZ;
```

However, it just increases gyro z value when moving and then brings it back to 0 when stationary.

Comment: Your equations make no sense without context .... do you have image/sketch of  your coordinate system, acting forces and measured values ? your complementary filtering does make sense to me. if you want complement then you should combine x and y not speed,acceleration ... What is the cause of the drift. Is it constant? do you got comparison between measured and real values (plot) to seewhat is happening so you can adjust filtration from that instead of blind guessing ...

Comment: @Spektre im using the MPU9250, it measures acceleration, magnetometer, gyro, etc. Comp filter tutorial for this is here: geekmomprojects.com/gyroscopes-and-accelerometers-on-a-chip however this tutorial does not have a magnetometer and I do, thus I thought I could eliminate the gyro drift.

Comment: so that is not a complementary computation .... instead its some derivate  `t/(t+dt)` like correction that makes no sense to me (but that does not make it wrong). accelerometers will give you down direction + noise and movement acceleration so its possible to project it onto YZ plane and compute the rotation to use for correcting your gyro angle ... simply take starting angle from gyro , then compute angle from accelerometers and the difference is your correction value to move from accelerometer angle to gyro ,,, from now on you have 2 values  so if gyro is moving more than accelerometer

Comment: remove the difference ... if they are moving the same remember actual offset. however this will not work properly in some orientations of the sensor ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Madgwick filter will work best. The link can be found [here](https://www.i2cdevlib.com/forums/topic/633-mpu-9250-madgwick-filter-drift/).
It is easy to implement (if using the correct library and the readings are pretty accurate. The only downside at the moment is that you will have to calibrate the magnetometer every time you want to use the device in a new direction).